# lodash check object.path is equal to value

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have an object like...

```
let object = {
    person: {
        pet: {
            name: "Rover"
        }
    }
};
```

And I would like to use `lodash` (or anything for that matter) to do a check like...

> Is the value at `object.person.pet.name` equal to `"Spot"`?

Currently the only option I can see is to get the pet name out of the object and then check if it is equal to "Spot".

Is there a function that I can use to make this a single check, something like...

```
_.equals(object, 'person.pet.name', "Spot");
```

This would be great to have if it exists either through `lodash` or not.

The reason I'm using `lodash` at the moment is that I don't know if person, pet or name will actually exist so lodash gives me a way to "safely" get that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that no such methods exist in **lodash**.

Anyway, you can use the `findKey` method that'll find the key matching the given requirements.

```
_.findKey(object, { 'person.pet.name' : 'Spot' });
```

If it returns `undefined` it means that it wasn't equal.

---

See the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#findKey)

```
var users = {
  'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }
};

_.findKey(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// => 'barney' (iteration order is not guaranteed)

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => 'pebbles'

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, ['active', false]);
// => 'fred'

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, 'active');
// => 'barney'
```

---

---

Non **loadash** custom function

```js
const object = {
  person: {
    pet: {
      name: 'Rover',
    },
  },
};

function checkEquality(obj, key, value) {
  const val = key.split('.')
    .reduce((tmp, x) => (tmp !== void 0 && tmp[x] !== void 0 ? tmp[x] : void 0), obj);

  if (val === void 0) return false;

  return val === value;
}


console.log(checkEquality(object, 'person.pet.name', 'Rover'));
console.log(checkEquality(object, 'person.pet.name', 'RoverTT'));
console.log(checkEquality(object, 'person.petak.name', 'Rover'));
```

Comment: i've added a custom function so you do not have to use loadash, only for that.

Comment: Even better! I think I'm going to adapt that custom function and use that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.flow()` to create a function that gets the value of a path with `_.get()`, and compares it to a values using `_.isEqual()`.

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, get, isEqual } = _

const pathEq = (propPath, value) => flow(
  pr(get, propPath),
  pr(isEqual, value)
)

const object = {
  person: {
    pet: {
      name: "Rover"
    }
  }
};

console.log(pathEq('person.pet.name', 'Spot')(object)) // false
console.log(pathEq('person.pet.name', 'Rover')(object)) // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Since lodash functions are not auto-curried, and the functions parameters are not in a the correct order (the data is first), I need to use `_.partialRight()` to supply parameters, and get a function.

We can avoid that by using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { useWith, flow, get, isEqual } = _

const pathEq = useWith(flow, [get, isEqual])

const object = {
  person: {
    pet: {
      name: "Rover"
    }
  }
};

console.log(pathEq('person.pet.name', 'Spot')(object)) // false
console.log(pathEq('person.pet.name', 'Rover')(object)) // true
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```